# Table of tables with captions?

Tags: tables, floats, captions

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    0 & 1 \\
    2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{table 1}\label{table1}
\end{figure}

&

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    0 & 1 \\
    2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{table 2}
\end{figure}

\end{tabular}
\caption{tables}\label{tables}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This produces the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

While I understand the error's meaning, I have no idea how to get my table of tables working. Any ideas?

Please note: I can not use another documentclass.

Comment: You cannot nest a `figure` into a `figure`. The same goes for `table` which you may have in mind? Anyway, take a look at the `subcaption` package http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf for subtables.

Comment: Side note: there is a floating `table` environment for `tabular`s you want to float.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I can not find any example where there is a subtable used with two tabulars. Could you please answer with a minimal example?

Comment: @Johannes I've added an answer with an example. Is this the thing you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following uses the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{.5\linewidth}%
    \centering%
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        0 & 1 \\
        2 & 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table 1}\label{table1}
  \end{subtable}%
  \begin{subtable}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        0 & 1 \\
        2 & 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table 2}
  \end{subtable}
  \caption{tables}\label{tables}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

For a second row, just add another pair of `subtable`(s):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{.5\linewidth}%
    \centering%
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        0 & 1 \\
        2 & 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table 1}\label{table1}
  \end{subtable}%
  \begin{subtable}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        0 & 1 \\
        2 & 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table 2}
  \end{subtable}\par\bigskip
  \begin{subtable}[t]{.5\linewidth}%
    \centering%
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        0 & 1 \\
        2 & 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table 3}
  \end{subtable}%
  \begin{subtable}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        0 & 1 \\
        2 & 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table 4}
  \end{subtable}
  \caption{tables}\label{tables}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but: How to align 2x2 tables, i.e. two additional tables below?

Comment: @Johannes It's just like adding some more text. See my updated answer.

Comment: This works fine. Alternatively, I found out one can wrap an outer `\tabular` around the small tables.